# Conditional recode based on lookup vector

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup, recode

I need to conditionally recode my dataframe `d` according to a lookup vector.

```
dput(lookup)
structure(c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"), .Names = c("101", "102", "102", "103"))
dput(d)
structure(list(pat = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103), gene = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), Apple = c(0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, NA, NA), Banana = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.55, NA), Carrot = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.6)), .Names = c("pat", "gene", "Apple", "Banana", 
"Carrot"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

`d` is a wide dataframe that I got through `reshape`. I need to recode any `NAs` within each of the columns `Apple`, `Banana` and `Carrot` to `0` if `pat` matches that column according to the lookup table. In this case, `d$Apple[5]` and `d$Banana[4]` would be recoded to `0`.

I've been toying with `recode` from `dplyr` but I have no idea how to get it to lookup and recode, not to mention that it has to be done on multiple columns... There was another related post on [recoding variables in R with a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823269/recoding-variables-in-r-with-a-lookup-table?rq=1) but it can't seem to apply to my problem. Can anyone help me pls? Thank you!

**Edit**

I tried the following:.

```
e <- melt(d, id.vars=c("pat", "gene"))
e %>% mutate(test=ifelse(lookup[as.character(pat)] == variable, replace(value, is.na(value), 0), value))
```

My code works partially. It succeeded in recoding the `NA` in `d$Apple[5]` but not in `d$Banana[4]` because the lookup can only give the first value:

```
lookup["102"]
    102 
"Apple"
```

whereas I need my lookup to be able to output both "Apple" and "Banana" and be able to convert `NAs` fulfilling each condition accordingly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no `dplyr` here but code is rather straightforward.

```
for(i in unique(lookup)){
    need_to_replace = is.na(d[[i]]) & (d$pat %in% names(lookup[lookup %in% i]))
    d[[i]][need_to_replace] = 0
}

d

   pat gene Apple Banana Carrot
1 101    a   0.1     NA     NA
2 101    b   0.2     NA     NA
3 101    c   0.3     NA     NA
4 102    d   0.4   0.00     NA
5 102    e   0.0   0.55     NA
6 103    f    NA     NA    0.6
```

Comment: It's a simple and elegant solution. Thank you!
I could apply this on an additional lookup `lookup2` that I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would work with the long format and use joins from `dplyr`.

I'd first get back to long format like the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
long_format <- d %>% 
  gather(fruit, value, -pat, -gene)
```

Then I would create the lookup as a `data_frame`, so we can use joins.

```r
lookup <- tribble(~pat, ~fruit,
                  101, "Apple",
                  102, "Apple",
                  102, "Banana",
                  103, "Carrot")
```

Using the `right_join` means, we preserve all combinations from the lookup. We then replace missing values with `0` and spread back to wide format, in case you need that.

```r
long_format %>% 
  right_join(lookup) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(value = 0)) %>%
  spread(fruit, value)
#> Joining, by = c("pat", "fruit")
#> pat gene Apple Banana Carrot
#> 1 101    a   0.1     NA     NA
#> 2 101    b   0.2     NA     NA
#> 3 101    c   0.3     NA     NA
#> 4 102    d   0.4   0.00     NA
#> 5 102    e   0.0   0.55     NA
#> 6 103    f    NA     NA    0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit patchy but I've managed to create a possible solution by looping

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  mtch <- lookup[which(d$pat[i] == names(lookup))] # Get lookup matches for row i
  colnum <- which(colnames(d) %in% mtch) # Get column nr that matches lookup value
  newval<-ifelse(is.na(d[i,colnum]),0,d[i,colnum]) # if it contains NA replace with 0
  d[i,colnum]<-unlist(newval) # replace the values

}
```

Output

```
  pat gene Apple Banana Carrot
1 101    a   0.1     NA     NA
2 101    b   0.2     NA     NA
3 101    c   0.3     NA     NA
4 102    d   0.4   0.00     NA
5 102    e   0.0   0.55     NA
6 103    f    NA     NA    0.6
```

Hope it helps